# Where to get simple opensource adpcm C\C++ encoder lib?

Tags: c++, c, pcm, encoder, adpcm

Where to get simple opensource  pcm to adpcm C\C++ encoder lib?

Comment: I'm flagging this as spam and marking to close, since you asked almost the exact same question not 20 minutes ago.

Comment: algorithm != opensource encoder lib! so I'm flagging you=)

Comment: He asked a different question IMO, there being a difference between the algorithm and an open source library.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the open source encoder library will contain the algorithm; why not just edit your previous question?

Comment: the only ones I know of are closed source, but it wouldn't surprise me if ffmpeg could handle adpcm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [sox package](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) can deal with several varieties of ADPCM both as a source and destination format.